# How can I read an Excel Date and store it into my database?

Tags: java, excel, date

I am trying to read an Excel Date value and store it into my database.

The following code is what I've got:

```
Date birthdate = null;
case 8:
       birthdate = cell.getDateCellValue();
       break;
```

The switch case is to store the Date in a variable and to put it into an array afterwards.

```
Identity id = new Identity(BSN, sort, birthdate, place);
```

I store multiple of those values into an arraylist.

```
for(Identity id : Identities) {
        System.out.println(id.toString());
        idmc.insertID(""+id.getBSN(), id.getSort(), id.getBirthdate(), id.getPlace());
    }
```

The getter and setter for date is obvious, but I'll post it just in case.

```
public void Birthdate (Date birthdate) {
    this.birthdate = birthdate;
}

public Date getBirthdate() {
    return birthdate;
}
```

Then to insert the values I get from the Array, I use this method:

```
public String insertID(String BSN, String SoortID, Date UitgiftedatumID, String UitgifteplaatsID) {
    String returning = null;
    try {
        query = "insert into Identiteit values(?,?,?,?);";

        pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(BSN));
        pst.setString(2, Sort);
        pst.setDate(3, birthdate);
        pst.setString(4, place);

        int response = pst.executeUpdate();
        returning = response +" Records has/have been edited";

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        returning = " ";

    }

    return returning;   
}
```

However, the line: `pst.setDate(3, UitgiftedatumID);` says: `Incomatible types: java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.sql.Date.`

I've tried casting like: `pst.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) UitgiftedatumID);`

But unfortunately that didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `Date` classes in Java: `java.util.Date` (a general-purpose date-time class) and `java.sql.Date` (JDBC-related class that represents date (with no time component)). `PreparedStatement#setDate()` method accepts the latter as its second parameter.

To convert an instance of `java.util.Date` to an instance of `java.sql.Date`, you could do the following:

```
java.util.Date UitgiftedatumID = ... // some value
java.sql.Date sqlDate = UitgiftedatumID == null ? null : new java.sql.Date(UitgiftedatumID.getTime());
```

Comment: Instead of initializing a Date I am using your code now. However, the `.getTime` part gives a comment saying: `Dereferencing Null Pointer` and so I am getting a `NullPointerException` on that rule, where I initialize `java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(UitgiftedatumID.getTime());` this.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed the possibility that the initial date may be `null`. I've updated my answer to handle this.

Comment: Thank you so very very much man! It's worked now! Finally the date shows up in my database. Thank you so much, have a great day!

Comment: You are welcome! Please don't hesitate to upvote and/or accept my answer.

Comment: Done! :D I almost forgot.

Comment: If you have (or can get) a JDBC version 4.2 JDBC driver, you should prefer to convert to `java.time.LocalDate` rather than `java.sql.Date` and then pass it through `pst.setObject()`. The newer Java date and time classes are generallt much more programmer friendly, and even if Apache POI (or what you are using for Excel) doesn’t yet support them, the sooner you can start migrating your app to them, the better.